# Will crawlers find content that appears after document.ready using javascript?

Tags: seo, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the Google spider render JavaScript?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/does-the-google-spider-render-javascript)

I have a page that initially loads and looks pretty empty, but after it has loaded uses an ajax call to populate the content on the page (usually in under 1 second).  Is this bad SEO practice?  Will crawlers find my content?

Comment: crawlers are unlikely to find your content. This is bad SEO practice