# Can Google see AJAX loaded content and how to test it?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, ajax

Since I knew that Google had some issue with pages with pages that load contents via AJAX I tested my client website with Google Search Console and How Google use my pages. From that tool Google seems to see just the body, since all the contents are loaded via Ajax.

I did a little research and found this page from Google 
https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

but at the top is reported that this guidelines are deprecated and links to a new page
https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

This article basically says that if a modern web browser can see the page Google also can see the page.

At this point it could be that search console tool is outdated, but I'm not 100% sure that Google can really see AJAXed content.

Any way to test it?

Comment: This question answers the question of whether or not Google sees AJAX loaded content: [Does the Google spider render JavaScript?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/does-the-google-spider-render-javascript)   However it doesn't answer the question about how you test it.

Comment: that answer is 7 years old, the last article I linked is from 2015

Comment: The question is old, but the answers are newer. There is one from 2015 that answers you question. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/63451/11903

Comment: Perhaps this article will help you https://searchengineland.com/google-will-stop-crawling-old-ajax-crawling-scheme-q2-2018-287653

Comment: And this https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/12/rendering-ajax-crawling-pages.html

Comment: so, since in 2015 google already said that they could render ajax page without any modification now in 2017 they are saying that it will be OK from Q2 2018? :-/